# C# - loading json file and converting to xml file

Tags: c#, json, xml, oop

I need a program that will load a json file and can update the fields ,
and after that convert the json file to xml file.

So I wrote 2 formats of json file.

1. with the first I can load it and update , but can't convert to xml.
2. with the second I can't load it like a JSon file (only like a string file) and therefore can't update it, but I can convert to XML file.

// Boxers1.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "Mike Tyson",
    "weight": 100,
    "height": 1.78,
    "teamName": "cuzDemato"

  },
  {
    "name": "Canelo Alvarez",
    "weight": 75,
    "height": 1.74,
    "teamName": "teamAlvarez"
  }
]
```

// Boxers2.json

```
{
  "Boxers": {
    "Boxer": [
      {
        "name": "Mike Tyson",
        "weight": 100,
        "height": 1.78,
        "teamName": "cuzDemato"
      },
      {
        "name": "Canelo Alvarez",
        "weight": 75,
        "height": 1.74,
        "teamName": "teamAlvarez"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

// Boxer class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JsonToXml
{
    [Serializable]

    public class Boxer
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public double weight { get; set; }
        public double height { get; set; }
        public string teamName { get; set; }
    }
}


// main 

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExampleOneSimpleClassObject();
        }


        // loading json file (Boxers.json) -> converting to json file(Boxers1.xml)

        static void ExampleOneSimpleClassObject()
        {
            string fileName1 = @"C:\Users\Natan\source\repos\JsonToXml\JsonToXml\Boxers1.json";
 
            string jsonFile1 = File.ReadAllText(fileName1);
       
            // loading json file to 'boxers' object
            var boxers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Boxer>>(jsonFile1);

// update for example:
            boxers[0].name = "Evander";
            boxers[0].weight = 112;
            boxers[0].height = 188;
            boxers[0].teamName = "teamEvander";

            // string fileName2 = @"C:\Users\Natan\source\repos\JsonToXml\JsonToXml\Boxers2.json";
            string fileName2 = @"..\Boxers2.json";

            string jsonFile2 = File.ReadAllText(fileName2);

            // converting to xml 
            XNode node = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(jsonFile2, "");
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Natan\source\repos\JsonToXml\JsonToXml\Boxers2.xml", node.ToString());
   }
```

Comment: Okay, so you've shown your data, and shown your code. That's good! But what's actually preventing you from doing what you set out to do? Are you getting an error? Or otherwise, how is this not working as expected

Comment: In contrast to Json, XML needs a root. So deserialize your json and set the list into a root object. Then serialize that to xml.

Comment: @Fildor , can you show me how to set the list into a root object ?

Answer (score 0):

you can convert to xml in one line

the first case

```
 List<Boxer> boxers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Boxer>>(json);
```

the second case

```
List<Boxer> boxers = JObject.Parse(json2)["Boxers"]["Boxer"].ToObject<List<Boxer>>();
```

update data, wrap it in a root and convert to xml

```
     boxers[0].name = "Evander";
    boxers[0].weight = 112;
    boxers[0].height = 188;
    boxers[0].teamName = "teamEvander";

XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(
  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Boxers = new { Boxer = boxers }}));
```

result

```
<Boxers>
  <Boxer>
    <name>Evander</name>
    <weight>112</weight>
    <height>188</height>
    <teamName>teamEvander</teamName>
  </Boxer>
  <Boxer>
    <name>Canelo Alvarez</name>
    <weight>75</weight>
    <height>1.74</height>
    <teamName>teamAlvarez</teamName>
  </Boxer>
</Boxers>
```

to convert xml document to string, in other to write it in a file

```
    string xml = null;
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            Indent = true,
            NewLineOnAttributes = true,
            Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        };
        using (var textWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sw, settings))
        {
            doc.Save(textWriter);
        }
        sw.Flush();
        xml = sw.ToString();
    }
   File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Natan\source\repos\JsonToXml\JsonToXml\Boxers2.xml", xml);
```

or if you don't care how xml looks, you can replace all the writers

```
string xml= doc.InnerXml;
```

Comment: the problem is not to convert to xml , the problem is to load a json file with a root , and update it  (i added the example to my code )

Comment: @NatiDim I updated my answer too